# jquery problem with addClass() & toggleClass() & default CSS value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

As you can see in following code, background not changes, but border changes.
The problem is with default background value.
How to solve this problem?!

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').bind('focus blur', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('focus');
    }); 
});
```

CSS:

```
input{background-color: blue;}
focus{background-color: red; border: 1px solid blue}
```

HTML:

```
<input>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `background` defined on `input` is applied to the tag because of its priority. `focus` is a class, while `input` is a tag.

Try setting :

```
input{
    background-color: blue;
}
.focus{
    background-color: red; !important
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome ! If my answer fits your needs, click the checkmark on the left. SO is community, have a look to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

The css is incorrect. dot is missing for focus.

```
input{background-color: blue;}
.focus{background-color: red !important; border: 1px solid blue;}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i forget to write the dot it in stackoverflow textarea.

Comment: It should actually work if the focus class is getting applied. Try giving important to background-color in focus class. Anyways please check my edited answer.

Comment: the issue here is that the input css style applies over the class style.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli, a ';' is missing in the `focus` style declaration for the `border` property, in your edited answer.

Comment: @Vince - Thanks for pointing out that I have put the missing semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

try write:

```
background-color: red !important;
```

instead:

```
background-color: red;
```

Also you can write this without jquery. Why you don't write following:

```
input{background-color: blue;}
input:focus{background-color: red; border: 1px solid blue}
```

Comment: And yeah Vince right, focus is a class, so you need write '.focus'

Comment: :focus class is better, in performance and less-coding.
but, earlier versions of IE8 don't support :focus Pseudo-class